# Write an equation which relates 399, 543 and 12345 in Python

Tags: python, operators

I am an absolute beginner.

What am I supposed to write?

so far, I've just written:

```
x = input("Input the first number: ")
y = input("Input the second number: ")
z = input("Input the third number: ")
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'relate'? The question is vague

Answer (score -1):

12345/543 has a quotient of 22 and yields a remainder of 399

Step-by-step explanation:

if x = 12345 ; y = 543 and z = 399

then x= 22y + z

Alternatively Mod(12345/543) = 399

You can write a programm for it like given below

```
enter code here

x = 12345
y = 543
z = 399

equation = 22*y + z

if equation == x:
    print('it is a valid relation')
```

Comment: the question as well as the answer is vague